# Having problems connecting AWS through Matab system

Tags: matlab, amazon-web-services, ssl, openssl, ubuntu-16.04

while trying to connect with AWS through the matalb system command.
status=system(aws...)
i get status 1
and the console print :
"Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."

The matlab run on linux ubuntu. i have installed opensll.
And when trying the same aws command through the terminal it works just fine.

Comment: can you specify your Matlab version (especially if it not ubuntu version) - also what library are you using to open ssl with Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

Ok Thank you all. 
I sloved it.
The ssl libs was not linked to th right libs.

Comment: @ben-peled Any details on what you did to fix this?

Comment: @Layoric. Libs of opessl and crypto came with matlab. i (renamed or removed) them and linked it with my ubuntu opessl and crypto libs.